# Are there alternatives to Solarized (the color scheme)?

Tags: colors, themes, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

[Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) is great, but are there other low-contrast color schemes with different colors that retain "contrasting hues (based on colorwheel relations) for syntax highlighting readability"?

Comment: This is very opinion based. What feels good for you may be horrible to the next dev, and vice-versa.

Comment: I disagree. I am not asking for a subjectively "beautiful" color scheme. I am asking for alternatives to Solarized which were designed (or perhaps engineered) with the same philosophy (low contrast, colorwheel relationships, and perhaps constant contrast between light and dark background mode). These things can be measured objectively.

Comment: Each of those characteristics may be measured, even with discrete units if you wish. The readability of each one is still a matter of opinion. Even so, asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic in SO - that's in one of the radio buttons we see when we vote for putting a question on hold.

Comment: I agree with @octosquidopus.

Comment: A trick I use - since you got two themes, you can find similar themes by entering both names into Google, i.e. "Solorized Tomorrow themes".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme

Tomorrow theme, look at this, very nice and compatible with a lot of software.

Comment: The same creator now also made the base16 theme: http://chriskempson.com/projects/base16/